# Android: start an activity with an Intent or an intent-filter

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I always start activities with Intents, but in the book which I'm reading an activity is started with an action parameter:
Not in this classical way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityResult.class);
```

But in this way:

```
String PICK_BUS_ACTION = "com.example.utente.decompilare" + ".action.PICK_BUS_ACTION";
Intent intent = new Intent(PICK_BUS_ACTION);
```

And in the manifest there is an intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityResult">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.utente.decompilare.action.PICK_BUS_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I tried both the ways but I didn't find differences. What is better? What is the difference?

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types, notice **implicit** and **explicit**

Answer (score 0):

The second one is used for starting of another apps.

Comment: But I also can start other apps with the intent